# requests tracking logger 

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mdc

I am stuck at tracking requests. It is easy to get the component name and time (using aspect-oriented programming) but I don't have the ID of request (requestID)

I need logs like this:

RequestID ComponentName Time

- Add547          C4      5s
- Search547       C1      5s
- Search778       C1      2s
- Add547          C1      15s
- Search778       C4      20s
- Search547       C5      10s
- Search547       C3      2s
- Search547       C2      1s
- Search778       C2      12s
- Search547       C6      55s
- Search778       C6      1s
- Add547          C2      6s
- Add547          C3      46s

in order to easily receive file like this, that is exactly what I am looking for:

RequestID ComponentName Time

- Search547       C1      5s
- Search547       C5      10s
- Search547       C3      2s
- Search547       C2      1s
- Search547       C6      55s

RequestID ComponentName Time

- Search778       C1      2s
- Search778       C4      20s
- Search778       C2      12s
- Search778       C6      1s

RequestID ComponentName Time

- Add547  C4      5s
- Add547  C1      15s
- Add547  C2      6s
- Add547  C3      46s

All my reaserch lead me to using log4j with MDC and SiftingAppender, but I am not sure if it can provide unique ID 
throught the whole request, since it goes through a lot of classes, subsystems and threads.

Could you tell me if it can be done without changing the original system? (It should be an external component). Do you know any tutorials which shows how to do this?

Comment: Why have you taggged this "aspectj"?

Comment: Is your stuff running in an application server, or is it a multi-threaded stand-alone program that you've developed?

Answer (score 0):

"The MDC is managed on a per thread basis." http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

So MDC will work across classes and subsystems automatically but you will manually need to copy it across Threads.